# Кастомный метод вьюсета выдает ошибку KeyError

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework, сериализация

Есть вьюсет UserVieset, который унаследован от djoser.views.UserViewSet. У вьюсета есть кастомный метод subscribe(), который осуществляет подписку на автора через эндпоинт localhost:8000/api/users/{author_id}/subscribe/ При пост-запросе к нему возникает ошибка
`Exception Type: KeyError`
`Exception Value: user`

Вот сам метод

```
@action(
        ('POST', 'DELETE'), detail=True, permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)
    )
    def subscribe(self, request, **kwargs):
        author = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            serializer = FollowSerializer(
                data={'user': user.id, 'author': author.id},
                context={'request': request}
            ).is_valid()
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        if request.method == 'DELETE':
            get_object_or_404(Follow, user=user, author=author).delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

А это сериализатор, с которым работает этот метод

```
class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.email')
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.id')
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.last_name')    

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = (
            'email', 'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            'is_subscribed', 'recipes', 'recipes_count'
        )
```

Важно отметить, что здесь нет и не должно быть полей `user` и `author`. По задумке, при успешно подписке в ответе должны возвращаться поля, которые указаны в сериализаторе Follow

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    """Модель подписок."""

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='follower',
        verbose_name='Подписавшийся пользователь',
        help_text='Подписчик',
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='following',
        verbose_name='Пользователь, на которого подписались',
        help_text='Автор',
    )
```

Собственно вопрос: почему возникает вышеуказанная ошибка, если я напрямую передаю ключ `user`